# CMake for non-C project on host without a C compiler

Tags: cmake

I'd like to use CMake to generate makefiles for non C project. I don't need a C compiler to build my project. As a matter of fact, I don't have a C compiler installed on the host machine.

My `CMakeLists.txt` looks like:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6)
project (the_thing.html)

LIST(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/Modules/cmake-pandocology")
INCLUDE(pandocology)

add_document(
    TARGET the_thing
    OUTPUT_FILE the_thing.html
    SOURCES the_thing.md
)
```

When I run cmake on my windows machine:

```
$ mkdir dict && cd dist
$ cmake .. -G"Unix Makefiles"
-- The C compiler identification is unknown
-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:2 (project):
  No CMAKE_C_COMPILER could be found.

  Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
  variable "CC" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_C_COMPILER to the full path to
  the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:2 (project):
  No CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER could be found.

  Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
  variable "CXX" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER to the full path
  to the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also ".../dist/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also ".../dist/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

Those two logfiles give no additional clue. How do I fix that project for it to ignore the absence of a C (and C++) compiler?

Comment: For [the `project` command](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/project.html#command:project) you *must* set the `LANGUAGES`.

Comment: That's amazing how you can work for _years_ with a tool and ignore such a basic thing (I always built C and C++ projects).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to explicitly say there are no languages.

```
project("the_thing.html"
    LANGUAGES
        NONE
)
```

That's from one of my projects, but it uses modern CMake (your minimum version is 2.6).  The above may work for you, but if not this should do it:

```
project("the_thing.html" NONE)
```